# Deadlock in __cxa_guard_acquire

Tags: c++, templates, static

First the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <type_traits>

// assign unique identifiers to types
template<typename ...>
class Family
{
static std::size_t identifier() noexcept
{
  static std::size_t value = 0;
  return value++;
}

template<typename ...>
static std::size_t family() noexcept
{
  static const std::size_t value = identifier();
  return value;
}
public:
using family_type = std::size_t;
template<typename ... Type>
static family_type type() noexcept
{
  return family<std::decay_t<Type>...>();
}
};

// usage
using introspection_family = Family<struct IntrospectionRegistry>;

template<typename Structure>
void addIntrospectData(DataType introspection[MAX_TYPES], DataType const& dataType)
{
  /* reserve index for this type in the introspection register */
  const auto num = introspection_family::type<Structure>();
  assert(num < MAX_TYPES);
  introspection[num - 1] = dataType;
}
```

This code give an integer to each type and I use it in some kind of C++ introspection implementation.

The application isn't multi threaded.
When I compiled it in `-O0`, sometimes, the call to `introspection_family::type<Structure>()` blocks at `__cxa_guard_acquire@plt` and I get a deadlock.

When compiled with `-O3`, I don't have any problem, but that might just be because it becomes very difficult to reproduce.

`__cxa_guard_acquire` is used to ensure that the static variable is constructed before we access it but here it should be irrelevant as I'm not even in a threaded application.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening ?

I use:

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 -O0 -g3 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS= -g -pthread -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2
```

And I use `gcc` (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) `5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My problem is precisely that I don't have it. When I extract this in a separate main, i don't get any deadlock.

Comment: Adding -pthread doesn't change the behaviour. here is the flags for compilation I use:

CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 -O0 -g3 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Werror 
LDFLAGS= -g -pthread -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2
And I use gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov There is only one thread in the process (but I will still sanity check the mutex when I can as it should be held by this one thread indeed.)

Comment: What is `identifier()` inside of `std::size_t family()`?

Comment: You're using `gcc`, so please provide [mcve] using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xbjMWsPYf) or other online compiler site.

Comment: It is possible that your code contains Undefined Behavior and with `-O3` compiler finds it and optimize it away. Since, as I point out earlier, your code has gaps, we are unable to spot it.

Comment: identifier() is defined just before the family() function. It just increments a counter when called.

The trick is in the static variables and the templates. We call type(), which calls the family function created from the template for the current structure we pass as a template parameter, which calls the identifier one time to init the static value in family with the identifier call.

Comment: It is possible, I couldn't create a minimal reproducible example at the time. Extracting stuff from the codebase would remove the bug.
The codebase was valgrind, asan, drd, helgrind, and cppcheck clean, but I mean it's always possible there was an undefined behavior somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the compile option `-fno-threadsafe-statics` helped. Since your application is single thread, this is OK.

I had a similar issue. However, the reason in my code was **recursion**. `__cxa_guard_acquire` will block when called recursively. A proper fix was needed. I did not check your code if this could also be your problem.

Additional info: The lock used might have a different name than `__cxa_guard_acquire`. It might also work with recursion, but this is compiler/libc++ specific and you should not rely on that.

Comment: It could be the problem as I have a static being init with another static in the example. But it wasn't happening all the time, so that's strange... And initializing a static with another static should work.

Comment: Oh you mean an infinite recursion like in https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/06/26/adventures-in-systems-programming-c-plus-plus-local-statics/ for example

Comment: I had quick look in this article. Yes, recursion like in the last example in the article.